# Verilog - Inverter with X input

Tags: input, verilog

I have an inverter with X input when my testbench start. So my output is X too.
Can i force my output is 1 or 0 when my input is X?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. If your inverter is a module instance, simply force the wire that is tied to the output.  If it is just an assign statement, just force the wire that's being assigned to.

```
module tb();

reg l_a;
wire l_q;

invtr i0(.q(l_q), .a(l_a));

initial begin
    $vcdpluson;
    #10;
    force l_q = 1'b0;
    #10;
    release l_q;
    #10;
    l_a = 1'b0;
    #10;
    l_a = 1'b1;
    #10
    $finish;
end

endmodule

module invtr (output wire q,
              input  wire a);
assign q = ~a;
endmodule
```

The force of the output happens at time 10ns and the release happens at time 20ns.  During this time the value is 0.

[image: Simulation Output]

Answer (score 0):

No.

An X value is the result of an error; it does not represent any well-defined value. Performing any kind of operation on such a value will also result in an unpredictable value -- another X.

You will need to figure out what is causing this error and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for an inverter. Providing an input X will always inherently give an output X.